# Alter table in mysql only for MyISAM tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb, myisam

I am trying to convert all mysql MyISAM tables to InnoDB without pick the already in InnoDB.

I have 6734 rows (tables in MyISAM format) using this query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE engine = 'MyISAM';
```

And I have 11218 rows (tables in InnoDB format) using this query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE engine = 'InnoDB';
```

So I want connect each result of tables in MyISAM for pass only as subquery:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

How this can be achieved? select subquery? My purpose is avoid to process the already converted to innodb because it will take a lot more time if I make a script as the following:

```
for db in `echo "show databases"| mysql`;
do
echo $db

echo 'SHOW TABLES;' \
 | mysql -D $db \
 | awk '!/^Tables_in_/ {print "ALTER TABLE `"$0"` ENGINE = InnoDB;"}' \
 | column -t \
 | mysql -D $db
echo 'finish';
done;
```

Comment: As per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html you must take care not to convert system tables (user, host) so you will probably have to write a small script to take this into account.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but mysql gives a warning when it tries to convert system tables and it doesn't convert it after all, so it is safe try to convert it because it will skip with the error. Also it can be avoided knowing that are the first X results in the output

Comment: 18K tables!  That is a sign of poor schema design.  If you are having strange performance problems; we can discuss that in another thread.

Comment: Suggest you read [my blog on conversion from MyISAM](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).  There are a number of subtle things that _might_ trip you up.

Comment: Thanks Rick! Yes I know that it is a poor schema design, it is the result of a lot cpanel shared hosting accounts using wordpress, joomla, drupal, etc from several years (and shared hosting clients don't care about upgrade his tables). With a lot WP accounts it makes easily that MyISAM crash some tables by bruteforcing or peaks in visits. So trying to avoid that problems with InnoDB and new mysql versions. I follow near Percona post, and indeed your post link would be very useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direct create the ALTER statements in SQL. if you have more SCHEMAS to ignore you can add them in the IN clause.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE `',TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`' ,TABLE_NAME,'` ENGINE = InnoDB;') as newsql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql')
  AND `ENGINE` = 'MYISAM';
```

**To use with shell:**

```
echo "SELECT CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE \`',TABLE_SCHEMA, '\`.\`' ,TABLE_NAME,'\` ENGINE = InnoDB;')  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql') AND \`ENGINE\` = 'MYISAM';" |mysql --skip-column-names |mysql
```

Comment: It says: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCH' at line 1

Comment: sorry my mistake change the word "as sql" to "as newsql"

Comment: yep, it seems that sql is a reserved word, probably better change to "result" or something more explanatory

Comment: you anwser is very good, but it will give me the strings only for alter table, but how I actually execute that output?

Comment: And I detect another mistake, you have missing a ` before to TABLE_SCHEMA

Comment: wait 10 minutes - i change it in my answer

Comment: ok, nice. But how I execute then the output in that query? it is outing as result only and not executing it

Comment: so you can execute all statements. it is possible that you must set the password or user by the mysql client  - echo "MY QUERY" | mysql  | mysql

Comment: It is not working since bash pick the ` characters as commands instead of quotes

Comment: Also I must skip the column names. I am doing this (but probably it is still needed scape the table name and table schema, but I don't know how to escape for avoid that bash complaints):

mysql --raw  --skip-column-names -e "SELECT   CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA, '.' ,TABLE_NAME,' ENGINE = InnoDB;') as result FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'   AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql')   AND ENGINE = 'MYISAM'" | mysql

Comment: i have add it in my answer

Comment: I think it is not needed use two times mysql command and avoid the echo if you use: mysql --skip-column-names -e "query"

Comment: yes you can use -e option for the query, but in this case you must pipe it into a second mysql client. The first client only outputs the generated queries and the second execute them